Cannot remove old solder
I can't remove the solder from the pads. I want to remove the capacitor and remove all the solder but I can't get it to melt. I've tried going to maximum temp, 480C. I tried using flux and solder wick. Nothing will remove it. I don't understand how it won't melt at 480C when I originally added it at 430C.
I am using a Mypovos 8588D soldering station. Should it be easy to just melt it? The reason I ask that is to help diagnose, I am new to soldering and have not had to do this so I do not know how hard it should be to melt solder.
I added a picture of the tips I used. The first one I was working with is the one on the left. I tried the one on the right just to see if it worked better.



What kind of a soldering iron and tip do you have? That makes A LOT of difference. You should include either the model or the picture of your soldering iron tip with handle. Or are you using a hot plate? You might need to combine two soldering irons or an iron and hot air or hot plate.

maybe because the iron is not at 480C ... maybe because the iron does not make a good thermal contact with the solder joint

@jsotola Or maybe because his iron is too weak for the job.

I am using Mypovos 8588d soldering station.

Let me ask this, should it be easy to just melt it?

Setting a soldering iron to temperatures that high is not really that good an idea; it oxidizes the tip. Is this leaded or lead-free solder?

Try heating the board with hot air at around 180°C, then try to desolder using the soldering iron.

Never heard of the brand and it only shows up on Aliexpress when I google it... That's all the warning signs you need. It very likely does not live up to the spec.

Anyway, looking at the link provided in a comment, the problem is very likely with the board design. It looks like they've tied the holes directly to copper pour on multiple layers. That makes it pretty much impossible to solder - period. The proper design would have been to place the cap in a hole with thermal relief + traces leading to the big copper pour - the cap itself need no cooling. Using hot plates is good advice for dealing with soldering on bad PCB designs.

Don't remove the solder.  Add solder.  Heat the solder on the pads until it melts, then pull the capacitor pins out of the holes.
Liquid solder on the tip and the pads transfers heat from the iron to the joint better than just mechanical contact.
Once you have the part out, you can remove the excess solder from the pads and holes.
There's some information about removing parts here on my blog.

The blog looks ok for 50 yr old designs but not a heatsunk ESC device or even a metalshield on a ground plane.

@D.A.S. It's far better advise than using a solder wick braid as seen in the question... The "pro" solution would be to use a hot plate + through-hole desoldering station, but then you need access to said equipment.

Agreed adding heat by molten solder works well for small jobs but the thermal masses are mismatched. A 300W stain-glass window soldering iron would be an appropriate size.  So adding solder would be an inappropriate mess here and very bad advice. (-2)    I've confirmed that on brass shields over ceramic hybrids.

Add solder if it has a flux core, regular solder won't get rid of the oxide layer. It's really the flux doing the most of the work.

It is impossible to desolder from a heatsink so much bigger than the tip of your soldering iron unless using a hotplate at 200~250'C but do not melt the solder.  One must also avoid prolonged heat from unsoldering the internal components.
Various techniques may be used. This is one method that takes skill.

preheat in 30 s to avoid thermal shock to 200~250 'C on a hot plate over an elect. stove.
secure it in a mini vice or equiv to prevent mechanical vibration and displace internal parts.
add a burst of heat to the surface external parts with a microtorch while pulling with a hemostat clamp.

Unsoldering the external parts while not unsoldering the internal parts, requires a temperature differential that must be be done quickly but not too fast to cause CTE thermal shock.
FWIW the external Cap should be ESR= 4 to 5 mohms such as Polymer types. You must understand the reason for this is Ohm's Law.
55A * 5mOhms = 275 mV,  I*2ESR = 15W ! but low d.f.

Yes I also discovered this while working on it some more. It seems that all the heat goes into the heat sink and fails to melt the solder. My continuity detector did not detect any shorts so I think I can try to put the wires back and the part is not yet damaged. Thanks!

Are you sure the "55A" written on the part is an actual current and not a just some branding/part number?

@Hearth yes I'm sure  https://www.brotherhobbystore.com/products/returner-3-6s-32bit-60a4in1-esc-v1

@D.A.S. Just looking at that exploded view with all the copper layers gave my soldering iron a heart attack

@pipe LOL, My old buddy used to solder for leaded glass that looked much bigger than a prostate tester.

Follow up, I was able to remove all the old solder! I used wire cutters to cut it off. Low tech solution but it did separate the solder from the head sink and now I should be able to clean off the pads using the soldering iron.
